# Generating reports through a form and the navigation pane

Tags: ms-access

Right now I have a report that is generated by clicking a button on a form. The criteria for the report is what the user selects in a combo box. That works fine, but when I click on the report in the navigation pane, it tells me to enter "Forms!Adjudication!Combo21" because that is the criteria it uses on the form. I was wondering if I can change that to say something like "Enter release event" that will show up when I click on the report in the navigation pane, but also leave the option to generate the report through the form?

Comment: where is this criteria: Forms!Adjudication!Combo21. is it in code behind the report, or is in a query that the report uses?

Comment: It's in the query that the report uses

Answer (score 0):

well since your query is looking for that combo field, when the form is closed, it wont find it. however, the query is already prompting you to enter a value, so you can just enter a value in that box and it will work fine. no need to over do this. if you are looking to change the label to "Enter Release event", then consider changing the combo box's name on the form Adjudication to something that will make sense to the user, like instead of "Combo21", change it to "ReleaseEvent". That way the prompt should return "Forms!Adjudication!ReleaseEvent".

sure you can do more here to, but like i said, probably not necessary to over complicate this.